# Flickering of absolutely positioned element when using mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

A flickering occurs on the red bar when scrolling down using the mousewheel on  [this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9mznL5g/8/). It's perhaps more obvious on [my live page](http://fabricepallaud.com/) (see the top menu bar). Strangely it doesn't occur when scrolling using the scrolling bar instead.

I can't figure out what is causing this mousewheel-related flickering. I should add, I see this flickering only the first 1-2 times scrolling, after that it doesn't occur any more.

```js
$(function() {
  var sticky_navigation_location = $('.nav_primary').offset().top;

  function sticky_navigation() {
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_location) {
      $('.nav_primary').addClass('nav_primary_fixed');
    } else {
      $('.nav_primary').removeClass('nav_primary_fixed');
    }
  }
  
  sticky_navigation();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    sticky_navigation();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 8000px;
}

header {
  background: blue;
  height: 150px;
}

.nav_primary {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_primary_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <nav class="nav_primary"></nav>
</div>
```

Comment: i see no flicker

Comment: Works fine for me (on snippet and live site) in Chrome.

Comment: On what OS and for which browser does this happen to you, because I can't reproduce that either.

Comment: Works fine for me too (windows 10 with chrome)

Comment: Wow that's concerning. I use Windows 10 (freshly installed) and Google Chrome too. The flickering is pretty obvious to me on the live page. Not sure what to make of the fact that I'm the only seeing that... Note: I see this flickering only the first 1-2 times scrolling, after that it doesn't occur any more.

Comment: Works fine for me too. But note that you can do this only with `sticky` positioned element and no need for any `JavaScript` code. Because that would involve a `scroll` event listener, which is still a very expensive thing. Scrolling is one of the most frequent actions your users perform, and executing JavaScript during those events makes it hard to maintain a solid 60 FPS (frames per second) scroll. The UI becomes out of sync with the user’s mouse/finger/stylus. This is called `scroll jank`. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9mznL5g/11/).

Comment: Gosh that's fantastic, I didn't know `sticky`. Thanks!